# For what values ​of "a" will we have the dim(im (M)) of the matrix smaller than 3?

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values ​​of  "$a$" will we have the $\dim(\text{im} (M))$ of the matrix smaller than $3$?

$$\begin{align}
M=   
\begin{pmatrix}
    a & 2 & 3 \\
    a & a & 4 \\
    a & a & a \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Your notation is unnecessarily obscure. Consider using the helping tools of this site to look for a tutorial of mathjax.

Comment: The [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) reference page should help you format the matrix correctly.

Comment: @Allan Oliveira: what did you try to solve this question?

Comment: I tried. Can I try solve transposing the matrix and using Gaussian elimination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

> For $$M=\begin{pmatrix}a&2&3\\a&a&4\\a&a&a\end{pmatrix}$$ to give $\dim(\text{im}(M))=3$, you need $$M:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R^3$$ to be an isomorphism. If this is not the case, then the dimension of the image is less than 3.

@AllanOliveira With $a=0$ you get $$\begin{pmatrix}0&2&3\\0&0&4\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=y\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ surely this dimension is $2$ ($<3$).

---

*Since OP already accepted the answer, I'll expand it. The map $M:\Bbb R^3\rightarrow\Bbb R^3$ is an isomorphism precisely when the matrix $M$ is invertible, this happens if and only if $\det(M)\neq 0$, so we need to find the values of $a$ for which $\det(M)=0$. Computing the determinant we get $$\det(M)=a(a^2-6a+8)=a(a-2)(a-4)$$ Therefore, $\dim(\text{im}(M))<3$ when $a=0,2,4$.*

Comment: Sorry. I wrote the wrong matrix.The second line is (a, a, 4) and not (a, a, a)

Comment: But for what values ​​of "a" is the dimension of image is less than 3?

Comment: @AllanOliveira if you find the values of $a$ that make the dimension $3$, then **all other** values of $a$ will make the dimension less than $3$.

Comment: But if a=0 the dimension of image is not less than 3?

Answer (score 0):

If a square matrix is rank-deficient, its rows/columns are linearly dependent, which in turn means that its determinant vanishes. Compute the determinant of your matrix and set it to zero to get a condition on $a$. There are some obvious elementary row operations that you can perform on the matrix to make it upper-triangular, which will make the computation of its determinant very simple.

Comment: Many thanks your response really helped me.